# ggplot: axes lines, values, and labels not plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I recently noticed that when I try plotting anything in `ggplot2`, both the x and y axes data (values, labels, lines, everything) are missing. I have tried to manually specify and enter the missing data using scale and theme commands, but ggplot still won't display the axes.

For example, the following simple code produces this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v2nP.png) on my computer:

`ggplot(mpg, aes(x=class,y=hwy)) + geom_boxplot()`

I have been using R and ggplot regularly for a few years and never encountered this problem until recently, but I don't know what computer/R/ggplot settings could have changed.

Interestingly, when I use base plotting functions there are no issues (both axes plot normally), so it seems like it's only an issue in ggplot.

E.g., the base code below produces this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7bBR.png) on my computer:

`boxplot(mpg$hwy ~ mpg$class)`

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling ggplot multiple times to no avail.

Any advice for how to fix ggplot? 
Thanks!

Comment: What version of ggplot2 are you using? I ran your code with ggplot2 v. 3.3.1. All looks fine using R v. 4.0.0

Comment: Wow this is bizarre. Are you using ggthemes or similar? When you uninstalled and reinstalled did you go and delete the package and for a fresh install.packages()?

Comment: Does the problem persist in a fresh vanilla R session i.e. not loading any previous workspaces or data. Is it like this in the terminal as well as any gui?

Comment: Have you loaded any other packages such as cowplot?